# Masstransit: saga, rabbit, mediator, outbox

Tags: masstransit

I'm using [masstransit](/questions/tagged/masstransit) Sagas and I need to use events from rabbit-mq and internal in-process events. Also I need to use the Transactional Outbox (with entity framework) function.
I tried to put them all together, but there were always errors: either I couldn't publish the message (because of the mediator context), or I had a serialization error in the outbox (because of the mediator context).
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the Transactional Outbox with Mediator, it can only be used with message brokers. If you're already using RabbitMQ, adding Mediator is only going to cause confusion and complexity without adding any value whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks! And how can I send non-rabbit event to state machine?

Comment: Why would you? If you're already using RabbitMQ, use RabbitMQ. If you weren't using a broker at all, you could use Mediator with the state machine, but you're already using a broker. Use it.